Renaming columns in the global environment
I have these data frames in R within the global environment:
file_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, samplecolumn = letters[1:5], value = rnorm(5))
file_2 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, sample_column = letters[6:10], value = rnorm(5))
file_3 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, othercolumn = letters[11:15], value = rnorm(5))
abc_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, samplecolumn = letters[16:20], value = rnorm(5))

For all data frames starting with "file_", if there is a column the name "samplecolumn", I want to rename it as "sample_column".
I thought that I could do this by first identifying all data frames starting with "file_", and then renaming them:
all_objects <- ls()

file_objects <- all_objects[grep("^file_", all_objects)]

for (file in file_objects) {
    df <- get(file)
    
    if ("samplecolumn" %in% colnames(df)) {
        colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "samplecolumn"] <- "sample_column"
        
        assign(file, df)
    }
}

Is this the correct way to do this in R?

The name all_objects makes it seem like it contains the data frames but it actually contains the names of the data frames so suggesting calling it filenames and instead of file use filename (singular) instead.

Do you want to get a list with the renamed data frames or rename the data frames itself?

Here is a base R way. Get the data frames with ls/mget, then lapply a function making the changes.
ls(pattern = "file_") |>
  mget() |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    names(x) <- ifelse(grepl("samplecolumn", names(x)), "sample_column", names(x))
    x
  })
#> $file_1
#>   id sample_column      value
#> 1  1             a  0.3567935
#> 2  2             b  0.1467364
#> 3  3             c  0.2088358
#> 4  4             d  1.9435469
#> 5  5             e -1.6413247
#> 
#> $file_2
#>   id sample_column      value
#> 1  1             f -0.2842375
#> 2  2             g  0.5040112
#> 3  3             h  2.5262186
#> 4  4             i  0.5083768
#> 5  5             j  0.7501698
#> 
#> $file_3
#>   id othercolumn       value
#> 1  1           k -0.17416173
#> 2  2           l -0.04321274
#> 3  3           m -0.16325477
#> 4  4           n -0.53594218
#> 5  5           o  1.11494155

Created on 2024-09-28 with reprex v2.1.0
Or, more simple, with setNames.
ls(pattern = "file_") |>
  mget() |>
  lapply(\(x) 
         setNames(x, ifelse(grepl("samplecolumn", names(x)), "sample_column", names(x)))
  )
#> $file_1
#>   id sample_column      value
#> 1  1             a  1.5820405
#> 2  2             b -0.6436687
#> 3  3             c -0.5669997
#> 4  4             d  0.9622013
#> 5  5             e -0.9325018
#> 
#> $file_2
#>   id sample_column      value
#> 1  1             f -0.3382037
#> 2  2             g  0.3404972
#> 3  3             h  0.2350941
#> 4  4             i -0.1942233
#> 5  5             j  0.7478564
#> 
#> $file_3
#>   id othercolumn      value
#> 1  1           k  2.3387201
#> 2  2           l -1.0179311
#> 3  3           m  0.3301583
#> 4  4           n -0.3459007
#> 5  5           o  2.2805970

Created on 2024-09-28 with reprex v2.1.0

data.table::setnames is nice for this.
> mget(ls(pattern='^file_\\d$|^abc_\\d$')) |> 
+   lapply(data.table::setnames, 
+          old=c('samplecolumn', 'othercolumn'),
+          new=c('sample_column', 'other_column'),
+          skip_absent=TRUE)
$abc_1
  id sample_column        value
1  1             p -2.679587590
2  2             q  1.392783492
3  3             r -0.391974271
4  4             s  0.006553375
5  5             t -0.373086481

$file_1
  id sample_column      value
1  1             a  0.3554701
2  2             b -1.2325984
3  3             c -0.3066686
4  4             d -0.1407742
5  5             e -1.3499631

$file_2
  id sample_column       value
1  1             f  1.22129539
2  2             g -0.06206181
3  3             h -1.61550283
4  4             i  0.61408114
5  5             j -0.38956958

$file_3
  id other_column      value
1  1            k  1.2756607
2  2            l -0.3802113
3  3            m -0.5724748
4  4            n -0.3463155
5  5            o  0.5670347

If you really want to clutter the df's back into .GlobalEnv, pipe into a |> list2env().

It's just the files starting with "file_", not "abc_".
